# Правильное создание релизного приложения в visual studio 13

Tags: glut, visual-studio-2012, c++, opengl

Подключил к проекту `glut.h`. Необходимо, что бы приложение запускалось на других устройствах. Как это сделать?
Что выставлять в настройках проекта и возможно ли вообще это сделать с подключенным OpenGL?

Comment: Вы пробовали запускать на других устройствах или пока только предполагаете? Если запускали, то какую ошибку выдает, если нет, то почему ждете?

Comment: Запускал на ноутбуке Win8. Дословно не повторю, разве уж завтра, но смысл в том, что при запуске приложения вылезает ошибка " glut32.dll не установлен."

Comment: ну так положите рядом с приложением её. да, сам glut обычно не идет по умолчанию с виндой.

Comment: Я понимаю, что glut нужно или установить или ложить рядом с приложением. Меня интересует, можно ли в настройках что-то изменить, что бы все это работало одним файлом? Тоесть меня интересует вот это http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread15180.html но в VS13

Comment: если Вы в билдере сделаете приложение с glut, то тот рецепт не поможет.  И там вообще то о пакетах билдера говорится, а не о dll (да, это похожие вещи, но не совсем).

Вам нужна статическая линковка. Но насколько я знаю, glut не может так линковаться. Но есть проект http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/ - он вроде может.

Comment: Вот это то, что я хотел узнать. Еще один вопрос. Что "подлежит статической линковке"? Тоесть к чему я могу применять тот "рецепт" по ссылке выше?

Comment: > Что "подлежит статической линковке"? Тоесть к чему я могу применять тот "рецепт" по ссылке выше?

это "перпендикулярные вопросы". Для статической линковки нужны правильные файлы (вроде с расширением .lib или .a).

То, что описано в ссылке - это как заставить билдер линковать статически его внутренние пакеты.